# Dialog с ActionBar'ом

Tags: android, activity, actionbar, android-dialog

Здравствуйте! Запускаю второе активити стандартным способом таким образом:

```
public void showCalendarActivity()
{
    Intent intentTask = new Intent(this, CalendarActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentTask, 1);
}
```

и получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если запускаю второе активити в качестве Dialog:

```
public void showCalendarActivity()
{
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
    dialog.show();
}
```

то получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существует ли способ получить такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. Dialog, но с ActionBar'ом сверху?

**UPDATE**

Воспользовавшись советами, добавил Toolbar и в манифесте задал стиль `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`. 
Вызываю первым способом, как обычное активити:

```
Intent intentTask = new Intent(this, CalendarActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intentTask, 1);
```

Получилось нечто похожее на желаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, почему-то календарь стал "прозрачным".
Как устранить эту проблему?
А еще, как убрать title с тулбара? В layout макете свойство title не задано.
И как отцентрировать верхнюю надпись?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А еще лучше вообще убрать верхнюю надпись тоже.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить Toolbar в разметку диалога

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, дельный совет, обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Заголовок тулбара можно убрать атрибутом title - в разметке или в коде. Заголовок диалога тоже в коде можно как-то убрать, запросив NoTitle как-то. Отцентрировать текст заголовка диалога - сложно и костыльно - лучше убрать. Прозрачным стало из-за каких-то атрибутов дефолтного диалогового стиля. Создайте свой стиль-наследник диалогового и там проставьте нужные атрибуты.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы Ваша Активити отображалась в виде диалога в файле манифеста установите следующую тему:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Либо, при использовании support library:

```
 <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, при использовании android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" активити ведет себя как Dialog, но появились новые проблемы, обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: чтобы вернулось отображение попробуйте тему android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" , для того чтобы убрать title, удалите параметр android:label вашей Активити в файле манифеста

Comment: Установка android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" помогла, а вот label пришлось выставить в android:label="", иначе устанавливался label по умолчанию, с названием приложения. В принципе, осталось разобраться, как убрать пустую верхушку, спасибо!